# How to refresh only a specific section of a page except using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a simple form to get user email address. But I also need to get the users name and age as well and display them in the page for only a one time. When the user submit his name and age, it will be displayed in the same page using HTML JavaScript DOM. Now what I need to do is that I want to prevent the whole page from refreshing once the user submit his email cause it will clear the users name and age which was given only for a temporary time and I also don't need to store them in the database as well. Is there have any idea of how to do that except using Ajax? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```js
function submitForm(){
    if (document.getElementById("age").value > 10){
        document.getElementById("postNameText").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = "You are not eligible to use this site.";
    }
    document.getElementById("showData").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Send</button>
</form>

<h2 id="showData" style="display: none;">Your name is <span id="postNameText"></span> and you are eligible to use this site.</h2>

<form action="process.php" method="post" style="display: none;" id="form2">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitData">
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you don't need to submit the data from the first from to the server - so the duplicate that your first attempt to ask the _exact_ same question, was closed with, should still be applicable - https://stackoverflow.com/q/71936208/1427878

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Do you want to use AJAX or not?  You have two different forms, which one are you asking about?  It looks like the first one doesn't submit to the server but instead just invokes a JavaScript function, whereas the second form submits to the server.  What is it that you're trying to change in these forms?

Comment: (Of course, instead of trying to _prevent_ a form submission for data that is not supposed to be send to the server, you could simply eliminate the form to begin with. Input fields do not _need_ to be in a form ...)

Comment: No I just need to learn how to do this if this was an actual form which need to submit data to there as well. Thank you for your  ideas

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
function submitForm(){
    if (document.getElementById("age").value > 10){
        document.getElementById("postNameText").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = "You are not eligible to use this site.";
    }
    document.getElementById("showData").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Send</button>
</form>

<h2 id="showData" style="display: none;">Your name is <span id="postNameText"></span> and you are eligible to use this site.</h2>

<iframe src="email.html" frameborder="0" id="form2" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Include your second form inside a new HTML file called `email.html` and this will prevent the page from reloading.

Thanks and best regards!